# Scala: How to deal with sequences in a Future for comprehension

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

Given the following methods that return a `Future`...

```
def getProducts: Future[List[Product]] = { ... }
def sendOrder(p: Product, n: Int): Future[Order] = { ... }
```

... I need to invoke `sendOrder` for each product returned by `getProducts` and in the end `yield` the number of products processed:

```
for {
  products <- getProducts
  // how do I iterate thru products and invoke sendOrder for each element?
  ...
} yield products.length
```

How do I deal with the list of products in the for comprehension above?

***EDIT***

Things get even more complex since I need to invoke a third method before `sendOrder` if and only if `getProducts` actually returns a nonEmpty list:

```
def doSomethingBeforeSendingOrder: Future[String] = { ... }

for {
  p <- getProducts
  // how do I invoke doSomethingBeforeSendingOrder before sendOrder and
  // only if getProducts actually returns a nonEmptylist?
  o <- Future.sequence(p.map(senderOrder(_,IDontKnowWhatThisIntMeans)))
} yield o.length
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont' know where that second arg to sendOrder should come from, but essentially you want to do something like:

```
for {
  p <- getProducts
  if p.nonEmpty
  _ <- someOtherMethodThatReturnsAFuture
  o <- Future.sequence(p.map(senderOrder(_,IDontKnowWhatThisIntMeans)))
} yield o.length
```

Future.sequence will turn your List[Future[Order]] into a Future[List[Order]]

Comment: The second arg is just the number of items to send... but here it's just a detail ;-) Now the question is how do I invoke another method *before* `sendOrder` and only if `getProducts` actually returns a nonEmpty list (see my updated post)?